# Notation for "set of leaves of a tree" when leaves are "repeated"

Tags: notation, trees

Having this tree, I need to specify the number of leaves (6) and the set of leaves.

Question: is this the correct notation to specify the set of leaves when there are some repeated or is there another way to specify them?:
**{ 5, 6, 2, 2, 2, 1}**?

[image]

Comment: X + - + t-shirt are also leaves?

Comment: Since the labels are not unique, I suppose the best way is the way you provided...  Maybe someone will have a better idea.

Comment: I would just say each leaf is labeled with any arbitrary number rather than saying that the leaves are repeated, although you might be able to get away with that if the context is clear.

Comment: @ConradoCosta no, those labels that you gave are not leaves.  Leaves are vertices in a tree that have degree 1.  That is, they are incident with only 1 edge.